# AngularJS - Get url in Server side in Application_BeginRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I am building an angularJs app and need to have application_beginrequest where I need to get current url in the browser.

E.g. localhost:60607/#/login : need to get /login
localhost:60607/#/activity : need to get /activity

Also whenever user hits a refresh or when page loads again and goes into beginrequest it should have the same response.

I tried with context.Request.Path but it gives "/" only.

Comment: really not clear what problem is. Using hash based routing the only thing server needs to do is send the index page that is requested before `/#`. Server won't see anything starting with `#`. All other logic will be handled in browser

Answer (score 0):

bookmarks are not sent by browser to server, bookmarks are used for navigating inside the page. You have to get book mark using javascript and send it using different parameter to get that bookmark value at server side.

Answer (score 0):

Data after "#" symbol is supposed to be client side only (usually browsers strip away those pieces, application servers usually ignore them).

If your intent is to provide users the ability to refresh the page using Angular you can:

- Provide isomorphic behavior (load the page server side) but if you are using Angular JS ver 1.x is not as simple as you imagine
- Provide double routing behavior (*):

  - avoid using the "#" symbol for url and provide user simple url like `/login` or `/activity`
  - manage your route client side using angular as you are supposed to do already
  - manage your route server side and provide the right view when requested
  - you can try to centralize the view management providing them using a controller instead of static content

Using the second approach is probably simpler, but you will find that:

- keeping the view state is possible only for simple views (the things get complex quite quickly we introducing multiple UI element state)
- to manage the double routing you have to find a compromise between client/server

Comment: it is very simple to refresh page with `#` routing... server sends index and angular does the rest based on hash. No idea why you say it's not simple

Comment: if you have a simple application that show static pages, I agree with you. There could be a lot of cases in my mind where is not so straightforward, always dealing with UI state and authentication. It's all based on how you your application bootstraps, works and manage authentication.

Comment: still better to get clarification from OP though... could be a trivial issue they are dealing with. Not a lot of detail in question

Comment: we need to redirect / stop redirect based on what the url is in the browser. And this url we need to get in application_beginrequest method. Let's say I reload / refresh a page, my beginrequest method would be hit and from here I would need to redirect the app to a certain external domain.